# Initialize a vector in a class?

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor, initialization

From a previous question I have learned that I can initialize 2D vectors in this way:

```
vector<vector<double>> Example(3);
```

instead of:

```
vector<vector<double>> Example={{},{},{}}
```

In this case I will have three "rows" available in Example, correct?

Now I want that initialization in a class:

```
    class Perceptron(){
     int NumbersOfRowsThatIwant;
     vector<vector<double>> Example(NumbersOfRowsThatIwant);
    };
```

Now the numbers of rows are defined only in the constructor:

```
Perceptron::Perceptron(int x)
{
  NumberOfRowsThatIwant=x;
}
```

But this is probably wrong, how can I fix it?

Comment: Use member initializer lists: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Answer (score 2):

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Perceptron
{
public: 
    Perceptron( size_t n ) : Example( n ) {}

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> Example;
};

int main() 
{
    Perceptron p( 3 );

    return 0;
}
```

The data member `int NumbersOfRowsThatIwant;` is redundant because you always can get the number of "rows" like `Examp;le.size()`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Perceptron
{
public: 
    using size_type = std::vector<std::vector<double>>::size_type;

    Perceptron( size_type n ) : Example( n ) {}

    size_type row_number() const { return Example.size( ); }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> Example;
};

int main() 
{
    Perceptron p( 3 );

    auto n = p.row_number();

    std::cout << n << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
```

If you want to have the default constructor with a predefined number of "rows" you can define the class for example like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Perceptron
{
public: 
    using size_type = std::vector<std::vector<double>>::size_type;
    Perceptron() = default;
    Perceptron( size_type n ) : Example( n ) {}

    size_type row_number() const { return Example.size( ); }
private:
    static const size_type DEFAULT_NUMBER = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> Example { DEFAULT_NUMBER };
};

int main() 
{
    Perceptron p( 3 );

    auto n = p.row_number();

    std::cout << n << '\n';

    Perceptron p2;

    n = p2.row_number();

    std::cout << n << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a member-initializer list for this:

```
class Perceptron {
  private:
     int NumbersOfRowsThatIwant;
     vector<vector<double>> Example;
  public:
    Perceptron(int x);
};

Perceptron::Perceptron(int x): NumberOfRowsThatIwant(x),
                               Example(NumbersOfRowsThatIwant)
{ }
```

But keep in mind that the order of initialization depends only on the order of declaration of the members, not on the order in the member initializer list.